# How to make an AJAX call to an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I want to do is pretty simple. I want to make an AJAX call to a specific html class, so that whenever the html page is loaded, jquery will make an AJAX call to that specific html `div class`.

For example:

```
<div class="targeted"></div>
```

In jquery:

```
$('.targeted')
```

I know that the syntax to make an AJAX call is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/something",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
```

But how do I implement this AJAX call to the `$('.targeted')` whenever the page is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: You're saying you want to put the content of the result of the AJAX call into your `.targeted` div?

Comment: what do you want with ajax call?Getting a view and fill the target html ?

Comment: @mayk Yeah, whenever the page load ajax get will execute on `targeted` div

Comment: @airsoftFreak if so you can do the T.J. Crowder's answer in document.ready function

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to display the result of the ajax call in the element, you update the element from within the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/something",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.targeted').html(data);
    }
});
```

That example assumes

1. You want to replace the content of the element (rather than adding to it); more options [in the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com).
2. `data` will be HTML. If it's plain text, use `.text(data)`, not `.html(data)`. If it's structured data, then of course you'll need to do more work to put the information in the desired form.

Comment: I really have to add the data to the html, is it not the best practice?

Comment: @airsoftFreak: I don't understand what you're asking in that comment. In comments on the question you've said "ajax get will execute on targeted div" which doesn't make any sense. If you want the data to go in the div, then this is how you do that. If not, update the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/something",
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('.targeted').text(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
  yourFunction();
};

function yourFunction(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/something",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.targeted').html(data);
    }
});
}
```

OR Drectly you can pass that method in document ready it will execute automatically

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//This will execute onload oof your web page what you required
  yourFunction();
})

function yourFunction(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/something",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.targeted').html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to wrap `window.onload` in `document.ready`. You can use either of one instead

Comment: Ya it was suggestion and i updated my code and now i think both way can work similar but style of execution is different

Comment: both works in different ways. `document.ready` executes after DOM is loaded, `window.onload` executes after contents are loaded. means `window.onload` is executed a bit more later than `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

For when the page is loaded, you use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Inside the document ready, you put your AJAX call. If the result you get is in JSON format, you need to include the dataType as well like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/api/something",
  dataType: "json"
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('.targeted').append(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

If the result is not JSON, then you can just append the data.

Also note: 
The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()` and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()` and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

Please look at [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like this:

```
$(".targeted").load('/api/something');
```

if you want to wait untill after the page is loaded, wrap it with `window` `load` like so:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $(".targeted").load('/api/something');
});
```

P.S. `$(window).load(..)` and `$(".class").load(url)` are two different functions